# Best URL APIs easy & free to use?

Tags: image, api, url

I'm looking for well-documented and free for commercial use APIs.

By "URL APis" I mean something like:

```
http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff
```

It outputs 600x400 px iamge with $000 background and #fff text. Just one link! Simple as that!

All APIs I know of:

Google Charts,
Google Maps,
Dummyimage.

(I know there are Flickr, Twitter, Facebook etc. APIs, but I'm looking for something else)

I don't have any requirements, just want to create a list of these. Any URL that generates content "on the fly" is welcome!

Any ideas?

Comment: @anonymous:- are you trying to ask a question on RESTful apis like google charts and all?

Comment: @Hans Engel, @Coding-Freak, thank you, I didn't know these are called "RESTful"! :) I guess that's what I'm looking for!

Comment: You could roll your own.

Comment: How would it know what text to give in that format?

Comment: What's wrong with the ones you listed?

Comment: I think RESTful is a bit misleading here. For example, the dummyimage API shown in the example does not have a RESTful syntax because there is no named resource... there could be also a lot of APIs using an RPC-style URL-syntax. I think he is just looking for APIs which are usable without registration/API-keys? I mean, every HTTP-based API is an "URL API".

Comment: btw, I think this question is interesting altough the topic is a little bit broad. But I'm curious what other handy APIs will show up here :)

Comment: @Malte, I know there is no easy answer to my question that's why I'm asking for a "list", I'm looking for something stable (website won't disappear in next few months), as easy as possible and usable (dummyimage is good for webmasters, but I'm thinking more about normal internet users, Google Charts is a perfect example of ideal candidate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Resizer.co](http://www.resizer.co/) is a simple service for resizing images.

Have a look at the [API Directory at ProgrammableWeb](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?tagtype=api&tags=). Set the protocol filter to GET, POST, REST, JSON-RPC or SOAP. There is plenty of stuff in there!